# Add array to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datframe df, with the `df.shape`: (971,1)

And I have an array with the `anarray.shape`: (971,80).

How can I add the array to my dataframe, so that I have the shape: (971,81).

I only find solutions where the array goes into one column, but in my case it should go into several columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need helper `DataFrame` with same index like `df` and then [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(anarray, index=df.index))
```